# How to start a custom Java protoc plugin

Tags: java, plugins, protoc

My custom Java protoc plugin demo is as follows.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        PluginProtos.CodeGeneratorRequest codeGeneratorRequest = PluginProtos.CodeGeneratorRequest.parseFrom(System.in);                 
}
```

Then compile it into a .jar.

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-p7=. protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar --p7_out=. src/main/java/proto/greeter.proto
```

But there was an error.

```
[libprotobuf WARNING T:\src\github\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\parser.cc:649] No syntax specified for the proto file: protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax versi
on. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:1: Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:3: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:11: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 235.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:12: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 130.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:15: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:51: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 254.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:52: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 202.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:53: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
protoc-gen-p7-1.0.jar:1:56: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 141.
```

Don't know how to solve

Comment: Well, the error message is quite clear about your malformed input file src/main/java/proto/greeter.proto

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I find python a pretty convenient language to create protoc plugins.

I wrote a little blog post about how to create and run one here: https://medium.com/cloud-native-daily/create-and-run-a-protobuf-plugin-9471e16e8ad